# Is there any different between the noun and gerund in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

There is a sentence: "Being prepared will help you to stay calm and safe."

Why they use a gerund in this case? Can I change it to "preparation"?

Thank you

Comment: You can certainly say *Preparation will help you stay calm and safe* though it has a more general sense than your sentence.  You **cannot** say *Being preparation...*

Comment: @WS2 of course, I cannot say Being preparation, thanks a lot)

Comment: _Preparations_ are things you do to be ready. _Being prepared_ includes your state of mind.

Comment: Saying ‘Being preparation’ means you are the actual idea of preparation, and I don’t think that’s what the sentence meant.

Comment: @KateBunting Good point. I should have added that to my comment.

Comment: @Buzzyy - See Astralbee's answer. I assume the OP didn't mean '_Being_ preparation'.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* change it, and it would make sense, but it would also mean something different.

- Being prepared will help you to stay calm and safe.

"Being prepared" is the *state* of preparedness. It means that you have completed your preparations, and you are ready, well-equipped, prepared to face something. The suggestion is that being in this state is what will keep you safe. Presumably, the inference is also that the knowledge you are ready is what will also keep you calm.

- Preparation will help you to stay calm and safe.

"Preparation" is the *action* of preparing. This would mean that the preparations themselves are what would keep you calm and safe. But what if the thing you are preparing for arrived while you were still in preparations? Would you be as safe? I would say not, and that is why this is **not logical**, even though it may be grammatically correct.

Comment: thank you a lot. Very clear